# SVG gradients doesn't work on Android 4 stock browser

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to use SVGs instead of PNGs at my new website. To achieve this, I created vector drawings in Corel DRAW X6, exported them as SVGs and placed in my HTML file as `object`. They're working great everywhere. But today I started to troubleshoot responsiveness and I stumbled upon this *horror* (he he).

Problem is with semi-transparent gradients. Here's the screenshot comparing stock browser and Chrome on Win and Android: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQSzM.jpg

What can I do to prevent this? Step back for PNGs?

Example of SVG code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<!-- Creator: CorelDRAW X6 -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" version="1.0" style="shape-rendering:geometricPrecision; text-rendering:geometricPrecision; image-rendering:optimizeQuality; fill-rule:evenodd; clip-rule:evenodd"
viewBox="0 0 5466 4646"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <defs>
  <style type="text/css">
   <![CDATA[
    .fil0 {fill:#434242}
    .fil4 {fill:#727271}
    .fil3 {fill:#9D9E9E}
    .fil2 {fill:#B2B3B3}
    .fil1 {fill:#C5C6C6}
    .fil5 {fill:#00A0B0}
   ]]>
  </style>
 </defs>
 <g id="Layer_x0020_1">
  <metadata id="CorelCorpID_0Corel-Layer"/>
  <path class="fil0" d="M55 0l5357 0c30,0 55,25 55,55l0 3225 -5466 0 0 -3225c0,-30 25,-55 55,-55z"/>
  <path class="fil1" d="M5466 3280l0 765c0,30 -25,55 -55,55l-5357 0c-30,0 -55,-25 -55,-55l0 -765 5466 0z"/>
  <path class="fil1" d="M2099 4100c0,0 -74,323 -83,328 -9,5 -60,88 -183,129 -123,41 -56,89 183,89l713 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 713 0c239,0 306,-48 183,-89 -123,-41 -174,-124 -183,-129 -9,-5 -83,-328 -83,-328l-630 0 -4 0 -630 0z"/>
  <path class="fil2" d="M2099 4100c0,0 -15,65 -32,137l1329 0c-17,-72 -32,-137 -32,-137l-630 0 -4 0 -630 0z"/>
  <circle class="fil3" cx="2733" cy="3690" r="137"/>
  <circle class="fil4" cx="2733" cy="71" r="24"/>
  <rect class="fil5" x="137" y="137" width="5193" height="3007"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I've put it in my question.

Comment: That doesn't seem to contain a gradient.